# Number Format Exception: Can't recognize string

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a `filereader` that will create up to 50 instances of customers, each with:

```
String last names, first names,

int birth year, month, day, and SIN number (9 digits)

double savings balance (private double sbalance), chequing account, and credit card.
```

The text file consists of nine fields, repeating for each customer.

```
Yang
Wesley
324917400
1996
8
1
3233.36
none
none
Tam
Christian
984635684
1996
6
12
none
10233.52
none
```

This is the method:

```
public static customer [] customerarray = new customer [50];
public static void readfile (){ 
String sb = "";
String cb = "";
String ca = "";

int counter = 0;
String thisLine;


try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bankinfo.txt"));
        while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
           customerarray[counter].setLastName(thisLine);
           System.out.println (lastname);
           customerarray[counter].setFirstName(br.readLine());
           System.out.println (firstname);
           customerarray[counter].setSin(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
           System.out.println (sin);
           customerarray[counter].setYear(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
           System.out.println (year);
           customerarray[counter].setMonth(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
           System.out.println (month);
           customerarray[counter].setDay(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
           System.out.println (day);
           sb = br.readLine();
           System.out.println (sb);
           if (sb == "none"){
              customerarray[counter].setSBalance("none") ;
           }
           else {
              customerarray[counter].setSBalance(Double.parseDouble(sb));
           }
           cb = br.readLine();
           System.out.print (cb);
           if (cb == "none"){
              customerarray[counter].setCBalance ("none");
              System.out.print (cbalance);
           }
           else if (cb != "none"){
              customerarray[counter].setCBalance(Double.parseDouble(cb));
           }
           else{
              System.out.print ("error CBalance");
           }

           ca = br.readLine();
           if (ca == "none"){
              customerarray[counter].setSBalance("none") ;
           }
           else {
              customerarray[counter].setCardbal(Double.parseDouble(ca));
           }

           counter++;

        }  
     }

        catch (IOException e) {
           System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
     customerarray[0].printSin();
  }
```

Output is:

```
Yang
Wesley
324917400
1996
8
1
3233.36
noneException in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:      "none"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
at customer.readfile(customer.java:81)
at customer.main(customer.java:38)
```

Why can't it recognize that 'cb' is == to "none"?

The problem occurs when I run the program - it crashes at

```
if (cb == "none"){
 customerarray[counter].setCBalance ("none");
              System.out.print (cbalance);
           }
           else if (cb != "none"){
              customerarray[counter].setCBalance(Double.parseDouble(cb));
           }
```

I uploaded the entire .java file and bankinfo.txt file to
[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?bkwc32x57psqujy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `cb.equals("none")`. Read [here](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/) for more clarification.

Your code should look like:

```
       if (cb.equals("none")){
          customerarray[counter].setCBalance ("none");
          System.out.print (cbalance);
       }
       else {
          customerarray[counter].setCBalance(Double.parseDouble(cb));
       }
```

*(No need to check `else if`, as it is either "none" or not.)*

Also, this should be applied to `sb` and `ca` as well.